# Excel - Latest date for a table of dates and checkbox values without VBA

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have the following table (; separates cells)

`Date; Values
2015-01-15; A,B,C,D
2015-02-15; A
2015-03-15; D
2015-04-15; B
2015-05-15; B`

How do I retrieve the latest date for each of the A,B,C,D values? I.e. the result should be

`A; 2015-02-15
B; 2015-05-15
C; 2015-01-15
D; 2015-03-15`

Without using VBA, formulas only. I am interested in Excel or Google sheet formula. Note: The domain of values to be searched (A,B,C,D) is known in advance. Had the values been in format Date;SingleValue it would be simple pivot table. But how to solve it in this peculiar case? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming dates in `A2:A100` and values in `B2:B100` then try this formula in `E2` copied down to `E5` where `D2:D5` contains one of each value

`=LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D2,B$2:B$100)),A$2:A$100),1)`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

If there is no date for that particular value you'll get `#NUM!` error

Comment: Great solution, thanks. Out of curiosity, MAX( {...} ) can be used instead of LARGE({...}, 1) right? Or is there some particular reason you would pick LARGE over MAX?

Comment: The reason I used `LARGE` is because it returns an error if D2 isn't found, `MAX` would return a zero and in some cases that "no result" could be confused with a real return.....but probably not with dates here. If you use MAX and it returned a zero to a date formatted field it would look like `1900-01-00` - you can use a custom format like `yyyy-mm-dd;;` and any zeroes would display as blanks